# jquery-ui switchClass fails under Chrome

Tags: jquery-ui, google-chrome, animation

I get a problem with the animation done by jquery-ui switchClass, when trying to change the 'right' attribute from a value in px to a value in percent. The problem happens only under Chrome (works under FireFox or IE).

The animation should just change the right attribute of a div from '90px' to '20%', but the div first goes to the other part of the screen. When i look into the debugger tools, the px seems to be interpreted as % : the sequence of values are 90px, 89%, 88%, ... 21%, 20%.

The following code reproduces the problem :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.21/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <style>
            .class1 {width:100px; height:50px; position:absolute; right:90px; background-color:#F9EDBE;}
            .class2 {width:100px; height:50px; position:absolute; right:20%; background-color:#F9EDBE;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="myDiv" class="class1" onclick="$('#myDiv').switchClass('class1', 'class2', 5000);">Click me</div>
    </body>
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use 'this' instead of jQuery selector. Also try to add 'name' attribute with the same value as 'id'.

Comment: Thanks, but the selector correctly finds the element and switchClass is called. The problem is that the div goes the other part of the screen, instead of going smoothly from first location to second location.